# Node Version Manager for Windows Blows Away NPM PATH

Tags: environment-variables, nvm-windows

I have been using NVM for Windows for a while because I work in different Angular projects which require different versions of NodeJS.

One issue I have with it is that when I need to switch between versions, my environment variable for the NPM path gets fouled up. I can run `npm -v` but if I attempt to run `ng v` I get the common error message:

> bash: ng: command not found

I then have to go through the process of setting up the environment variable.

Is there anything I can do to stop the environment variable from getting blown away when switching between versions of node using nvm?